# Are users coming from Google confused about what answer will be best for their problem?

Tags: discussion, answers

In a discussion about using downvotes on PMSE, CodeGnome, as well as a few other users, point out that [some questions tend to get competing answers](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/480/34) due to the subjective nature of project management.

Have you ever done a search for a solution to a project management problem and found a link to a PMSE post?  For questions with multiple answers, did you find it confusing?  Or were you able to use that information to make a decision that was best for your project?  Did the PMSE post just leave you with more unanswered questions, or did it solve your problem?

If it left you with more questions, would you say the post at least helped you get from point A to point B, even if that particular PMSE post didn't directly solve the problem?

I use [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) a lot at work, and I generally find helpful posts via Google searches. Generally, one of the top answers helps me solve my problem. If it doesn't, it at least generally leads me to other searches that gets me closer to a final solution.

If you've used PMSE in your daily work, it would be interesting to hear what your experience was as someone looking for answers. It would be interesting to see if the multitude of correct answers is interpreted as a problem or not or if it was helpful in eventually locating a solution.

Anyone with at least 5 reputation on PMSE can weigh in. If you're a new user or just someone who visits the site, and you have a strong opinion on this, you could suggest a few edits or answer a question you know the answer to, so that you can get the 5 points needed to post here on meta.